# Workitem Tree copy in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, devops

I need to copy the wokritem tree, Like for example :
Feature- Userstories- tasks
While copy the feature, I need Userstories under feature and Task under Userstories

When I am trying to do " create copy work item" its copied feature and users Stories not task.

Comment: According to [Copy or clone a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#copy-or-clone-a-work-item): _“Include child work items: To include existing links to child work”_
> items in the copied work item. This feature isn't recursive.

Comment: here, its not copy sub child work items, for example, while copy the feature its just copy the user stories not task, i want to copy the workitem tree or workitem hierarchy. Or else any API to copy workitem tree